# How to use FLUSHDB ASYNC with RedisTemplate?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

Redis 4.0.0+ support flushdb async,
but i can't find it on RedisServerCommands,
is there any way to use flushdb async?

Answer (score 0):

`FLUSHDB ASYNC` isn't implemented in Spring Data Redis. You might want to file a ticket at http://jira.spring.io.